# Why can't I photoshop at high settings?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I set my settings high (1920px - 1080px, 300ppi, RGB 32bit) I can't photoshop anymore...
I can't make a new layer, I can't unlock the background, I can't do pretty much anything.

Comment: This could be a licence issue or bad installation causing features for 32 bit color modes to be blocked so you will just have to use 16 bit and lower. See more [here](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/why_cant_i_edit_32_bit_images_in_cs5).

Comment: Sidebar.. I really dislike using "photoshop" as a verb :) It's not very descriptive at all. What does "I can't Photoshop" even mean?

Comment: @Scott but, "that image was clearly photoshopped," leads me to think its culturally acceptable. Maybe it'll even get added to the dictionary eventually.

Comment: @Ryan.. yup I realize it's used.. but it always just seems wrong :) "My dinner was stoved", "My hair was scissored.", "That lawn was mowered."  -- Just not right :)

Comment: @scott can you go play somewhere else? I need an answer.

Comment: Well, a good answer would *start* by you explaining what "I can't Photoshop" means. "Can't do pretty much anything" is also very non-descriptive. Do brushes work? Can you add layers?   Does ACEkin's answer address anything? My point with the comments was, your question is not very detailed or clear. Clarifying the question can only help garner more or better answers. Realize we can't see your screen, we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @Ryan You're totally right, that's how linguistic works, languages are evolving with technology and photoshop will become a verb the same way google is used as verb. Not many people cannot actually understand the "verb" photoshop unless they're born at the beginning of the century or aren't very comfortable with technology. This could be asked on the english language learners forum on SE!

Answer (score 4):

In Photoshop 32-bit mode restricts some operations and allows only some adjustments and adjustment layers be used. The dimensions you indicate are not particularly "high". I was able to create a 2000x2000 pixels 32-bit image with no problem and the adjustment layers shown in the enclosed image shows the ones that are not available. Also look under "Image/Adjustments" menu to see other directly applicable adjustments to a layer. If you cannot do these things then there is a problem with your Photoshop installation.
[image: Adjustment Layers not available in 32 bit]

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of your graphic card and/or because some actions in Photoshop are simply not integrated yet to be rendered in that 32 bits mode for some (past and present) versions of Photoshop.